# Trouble with setwd() and getwd()

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using Rmarkdown for a projet. Yesterday i had no issue changing my working directory, but today, Whenever I try to put a directory as my workspace it doesn't, as if it's fixed on the same directory.
here is the console for further details

> setwd(choose.dir()):
> The working directory was changed to C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/Etudes/Data/Covid-related/csse_covid_19_daily_reports inside a notebook chunk. The working directory will be reset when the chunk is finished running. Use the knitr root.dir option in the setup chunk to change the working directory for notebook chunks.

> getwd()
> [1] "C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/Etudes/ADES/DM 2"

Comment: Try  in chunk: ```{r setup} knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = 'C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/Etudes/ADES/DM 2') ``` and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

What the warning message is saying is that it is possible to temporarilly change your working directory within a chunk, but this will not affect subsequent chunks. In other words, it is incorrect to say that R is not changing your working directory, rather it's doing so only for a limited place in your script. As soon as that chunk is done running, R will bring you back to the working directory in which your .Rmd document is saved.

Unfortunately you don't specify why you need to change working directory, so I will assume  that you either need to read something from a specific directory, or to write something. I believe that you may have three options:

1. You could move the documents you need to access to the same working directory as your script. This is most of the times not optimal, expecially if you have many documents.
2. Read whatever you need to read by specifying the whole path inside the reading function
3. You may want to specify the root directory by using the root.dir argument in the initial settings chunk. This would work as:

```
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(root.dir = 'C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/Etudes')
```

Unfortunately you still need to specify a path each time you need to read in a document if it's not in the folder you set as your root directory, but at least it is easier to do so by specifying the path in relative terms.

In general, my suggestion is to have documents of a project organised in a way that makes things easier to be accessed.